# Problems with characters when getting data from Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have a problem getting data previously recorded with my java program fronted in a Mysql Database. I checked both mysql and Netbeans and the encoding is utf-8 but I still have this kind of problem.
Any tips ??

I'm on mac with netbeans 8.2

My application shows the data like this:

[image: My application]

MySQL shows the data with no issues:

[image: This is when I read from database]

Comment: You haven't shown any code, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: If it's in a blob, you should consider it as binary and convert it to the type you need

Answer (score 0):

The question is not precise enough, hence some points you might try.

Add those statements in your java frontend application, after database is connected, before you INSERT any data:

```
SET character_set_connection="utf8"
SET character_set_client="utf8"
SET character_set_database="utf8"
SET character_set_results="utf8"
SET character_set_server="utf8"
SET character_set_system="utf8"
```

Probably you won't need them all; feel free to experiment which ones do the trick.

You may also log into a MySQL console and see actual settings by issuing a command:

```
mysql> show variables like '%character_set%';
```

Comment: Update...during my test I see that this problem is only with JTextArea in fact JTextField receive data correctly.So I quite sure that the problem is the component

Comment: I think that problem is Blob content, I tried to get bytes and convert in Utf-8 and ISO-8859-1 but nothing is changed....I also tried to change Blob in Longtext and change data in "è", I have a mysql error of syntax....

Comment: Solved: The problem was Blob Content; using TEXT or MEDIUM TEXT I solved everything....For Users that have problems with special characters, the best way to store Strings  in Mysql is Prepared Statement

Answer (score 0):

this is the code that a generate JTextArea and all data

```
 private void popolaPianificazione(){

    String tipo="Pianificazione";
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM DomandePianificazione";
    ResultSet res = null;
    try {
        res = MysqlStuff.richiediDatiSQL(sql);
        if(res != null){

            res.last();
            if(res.getRow() != 0){
                res.beforeFirst();

                while(res.next()){
                    final String contatore = res.getString("id");
                    int conta  = Integer.parseInt(contatore);
                    JPanel temp = new javax.swing.JPanel(new MigLayout("fill","grow"));
                    temp.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("DOMANDA "+"["+conta+"]"));
                    String domande = res.getString("Domanda");
                    domande.replace("è", "p");
                    javax.swing.border.Border border = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
                     JTextArea domanda = new javax.swing.JTextArea(domande,2,2);
                    domanda.setBorder(border);
                    domanda.setBackground(colore);
                    domanda.setSize(400, 100);
                    domanda.setFont(font);
                    domanda.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400,100));
                    domanda.setLineWrap(true);
                    domanda.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                    domanda.setOpaque(false);
                    domanda.setEditable(false);
                    JCheckBox rispostaC = new javax.swing.JCheckBox("Si/No");
                    JCheckBox rispostaCom = new javax.swing.JCheckBox("A completamento");
                    String rispostaCheck = res.getString("rispostaCheck");
                    String rispostaCompleta = res.getString("rispostaCompleta");
                    if (!"no".equals(rispostaCheck)){

                        rispostaC.setSelected(true);
                    }
                    else{

                    rispostaCom.setSelected(true);
                    }
                    JButton edit = new javax.swing.JButton("Modifica la domanda");

                    ButtonGroup buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
                    buttonGroup1.add(rispostaC);
                    buttonGroup1.add(rispostaCom);
                    rispostaC.setEnabled(false);
                    rispostaC.setRolloverEnabled(false);
                    rispostaCom.setEnabled(false);
                    rispostaCom.setRolloverEnabled(false);

                    temp.add(edit,"wrap");

                    edit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){               
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                           if ("Salva le modifiche".equals(edit.getLabel())){
                             System.out.println("Sto salvando...");
                             String pannello = "DomandePianificazione"; 

                               try {
                                   SalvaDomanda(tipo,contatore,domanda,rispostaC,rispostaCom,pannello);

                                   PanelPianificazione.revalidate();
                                   PanelPianificazione.repaint();
                               } catch (SQLException ex) {
                                   Logger.getLogger(ManageQuestionario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                               }
```

SKIP

and this is the code for send data to mysql:

```
         public  static void inviaDatiSQL(String sql,String stat) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
             UP = connetti();
     System.out.println("INVIO dati a DB: \n"+ sql);
     Statement stmt = null;

             PreparedStatement test = UP.prepareStatement(sql);
             test.setString(1, stat);

     test.executeUpdate();
     System.out.println("Finito !");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved it.
basically It was a problem about Column data in Mysql that it was BLOB...I already tried to change in LONGTEXT, but even if all Database was in UTF-8 if I changed only type of content it wasn't enough !.
I Had to change both type of collation,  Database and Column table.

Thanks for your support !

Alex